# jQuery load content when history url changes

Tags: jquery, history

I'm loading my content with this function:

```
$(".sublink, .button-link, .single-link").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#content").load($(this).children("a").attr('href'));
});
```

I now builded another function to dynamically replace the content and also change the url. This works great so far except that I now can't call $(this) to load the content again because it is another function.

```
$(function () {
    if (Modernizr.history) {
        $("#sidebar-left").delegate("a", "click", function () {
            _href = $(this).attr("href");
            history.pushState(null, null, _href);
        });
    }

    $(window).bind("popstate", function () {
        _link = location.pathname.replace(/^.*[\\/]/, "");

        $("#content").load($(this).children("a").attr('href'));
        ^^ CAN'T USE $(this) HERE
    });
});
```

So atm the url changes but doesn't load the href because I don't know the current element I clicked on (the $(this) of the loading function).

Any ideas what I could do?

Comment: It is unclear what you are actually trying to do here, but in general, you don't have access to `history` except to basically simulate a user clicking on the forward or back button. You can't read what the actual urls are in `history` or change their values.  And of course your javascript variable isn't going to carry over on page reload.. that's not how javascript works. In general if you want that info to carry over, you must store it in a cookie or else use a server-side session variable.

Comment: I thought of using a simple history.back() but that doesn't work. I can call _href but it again is only the current page. Are there any disadvantages by storing the previous url information in a cookie?